# Remove extra dash from url

Tags: php, preg-replace, substr

I have a blog system where user enter title and from it i make url here is the function to create url

```
function create_slug($string){     
    $replace = '-';         
    $string = strtolower($string);     

    //replace / and . with white space     
    $string = preg_replace("/[\/\.]/", " ", $string);     
    $string = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_\s-]/", "", $string);     

    //remove multiple dashes or whitespaces     
    $string = preg_replace("/[\s-]+/", " ", $string);     

    //convert whitespaces and underscore to $replace     
    $string = preg_replace("/[\s_]/", $replace, $string);     

    //limit the slug size     
    $string = substr($string, 0, 100);     

    //slug is generated     
    return $string; 
}
```

If user enter title "hello how are you" then it becomes "hello-how-are-you"!

Now the Problem I'm facing is that if user give extra space after "you " then it becomes "hello-how-are-you-".
how to avoid this extra dash?

Comment: *trim()* the values; Also you may want to look at `preg_replace` in the manual. Will save you a lot of function calls

Comment: @Rizier123 you can do answer from your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like Rizier123 says `trim()` will delete spaces before and after the entered value, don't forget that you have to `trim()` before you replace all the spaces with dashes.

Because:

`trim()` will make from `"hello how are you "` => `"hello how are you"`

but from `"hello-how-are-you-"` it will make `"hello-how-are-you-"`

Comment: ps: you can enter an argument into trim() to specify what it should trim (space is included as a standard, but you could enter whatever you wanted :) ) 


Link for documentation about trim: http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is create slugs for the title. Here is a [link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/create-url-slug-from-post-title/) for the same.